# Python FPDF - add_font() function can not read the location of TTF file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, fonts, jupyter-notebook, path, fpdf

I have a python file in ***1.code*** folder which will generate a pdf. I am redirecting a new font file(.ttf) in the ***2.font*** folder. At the end, my pdf file will save on ***2.Reports>1.January*** folder.

Now the problem is when I trying to save the pdf an error occurred that says:

```
no such file or directory: 'font//gothambold.ttf'
```

But my folder name is ***2.font*** but where does the ***font*** folder come from in the error message? and why does this error occur?

**Note:** I am running this file in **jupyter notebook** and I also changed the path name while redirecting any folder.
Thanks.

[image: My file directory]

Comment: i even renamed the folder into font. but it shows the same error.

Answer (score -1):

save font in *C>Windows>Fonts* location.
I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: but this is a custom font. i don't have permission to save this location.